# saving multiple checkbox to database in PHP

Tags: php, html

i am having problem in printing the values of the different checkbox with the same name & different values..

**PHP**

```
//$infect_type=array();
$infect_type = isset($_POST['infect_type']) ? $_POST['infect_type'] : null;

$values= implode(",",$infect_type);
print_r($values);
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="infect_type" value="Blood Born" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="infect_type" value="Air Born" />
```

i can only get the value which is selected last before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array notation for checkboxes names:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="infect_type[]" value="Blood Born" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="infect_type[]" value="Air Born" />
```

In this case `$_POST['infect_type']` is going to be an array of checked values.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="infect_type[]" value="Blood Born" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="infect_type[]" value="Air Born" />
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
        $infect_type = $_POST['infect_type'];
        foreach ($infect_type as $i) {
                echo $i;
                //Change the code here
        }
?>
```

This will do.